# Universal field for mysql join query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables A & B. Both the tables have country codes.

```
Table A
1 ALL
2 IN

Table B
1 IN
2 ALL
```

Here ALL means all countries. I want to join these 2 tables on Id and try to get insecection between the 2.This should be my sql output.

```
Output
1. IN
2. IN
```

When i do a normal inner join or join, it returns empty. Is they way i can default "ALL" as universal field ?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.country_code as CountryCode , IF(a.country_name = 'ALL', b.country_name, a.country_name) as CountryName
  FROM A as a join B as b on a.id = b.id;
```